# What if setState is used to fetch API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was experimenting with react. and used setState as shown below.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
export default function App() {
  const [state,setState]=useState([]);

  const fetchApi= async()=>{
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(response=>response.json())
                .then(data=>{console.log(data); return data})
                .catch(err=>console.log(err))
  }
  setState(fetchApi());
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In above code, setState is called again and again(infinitely). Can you please provide some explanation what exactly is happening behind the scene?

I know this is not the way of making an API call. One should always use useEffect to fetchdata and set the state accordingly. But I am curious about this one.

Comment: *"setState is called again and again(infinitely)"* - Because `setState` triggers a re-render, and you're calling it in the render of the component.  (You're also setting state to *a Promise*, which is almost assuredly not going to do what you want.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Under what conditions does setState from the useState hook cause a re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69996447/react-under-what-conditions-does-setstate-from-the-usestate-hook-cause-a-re-ren)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling "setState" in the body of the compnent, what will happen is : the compnent will render, and while rendering it will call setState which will update the state and force the component to rerender which in turn will set the state again and force the component to rerender and so forth, and you will be caught in an infinite loop;
to get arround this wrap the set state in a useEffect hook